# Does protobuf-net support C# 9 positional record types?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm trying to use protobuf-net with C# positional record types, and I've encountered this exception:

```
10:18:48.048 [EROR] #010 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel) Connection id ""0HM4NDHMUB3C6"", Request id ""0HM4NDHMUB3C6:00000003"": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. ProtoException: No parameterless constructor found for Bidirectional.Demo.Common.Contracts.Server.GetServerProcessI
nfo.GetServerProcessInfoResponse", DebugException="ProtoBuf.ProtoException: No parameterless constructor found for Bidirectional.Demo.Common.Contracts.Server.GetServerProcessInfo.GetServerProcessInfoResp
onse
   at ProtoBuf.Internal.ThrowHelper.ThrowProtoException(String message, Exception inner) in /_/src/protobuf-net.Core/Internal/ThrowHelper.cs:line 70
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.ThrowCannotCreateInstance(Type type, Exception inner) in /_/src/protobuf-net.Core/Meta/TypeModel.cs:line 1666
   at proto_12(State& , GetServerProcessInfoResponse )
   at ProtoBuf.Internal.Serializers.SimpleCompiledSerializer`1.ProtoBuf.Serializers.ISerializer<T>.Read(State& state, T value)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.State.ReadAsRoot[T](T value, ISerializer`1 serializer)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.State.DeserializeRoot[T](T value, ISerializer`1 serializer)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize[T](ReadOnlySequence`1 source, T value, Object userState)
   at ProtoBuf.Grpc.Configuration.ProtoBufMarshallerFactory.ContextualDeserialize[T](DeserializationContext context)
```

This is what GetServerProcessInfoResponse looks like:

```
[ProtoContract]
public record GetServerProcessInfoResponse(
    [property: ProtoMember(1)] TimeSpan TotalProcessorTime,
    [property: ProtoMember(2)] TimeSpan UserProcessorTime,
    [property: ProtoMember(3)] TimeSpan PrivilegedProcessorTime,
    [property: ProtoMember(4)] string CurrentMemoryUsage,
    [property: ProtoMember(5)] string PeakMemoryUsage,
    [property: ProtoMember(6)] int ActiveThreads
);
```

The code works fine if I change GetServerProcessInfoResponse into a regular C# class with gettable and settable properties. I was hoping however that records could work too, because they avoid a whole lot of nullability warnings. System.Text.Json has support for deserializing records for example, which has to work against the same limitations.

I couldn't find anything in the docs, issues or here on StackOverflow, so maybe I'm bad at searching, or maybe the answer isn't out there yet. :-)

The protobuf-net repository also doesn't seem to have any unit tests that try to serialize / deserialize a c# record, it only contains "RecordTypeTests" which seems to be checking if records can be cloned?

Comment: There is no real magic to records, they are just compiler generated classes with some interface implementations

Comment: OK so if I understand correctly, that means the question becomes: "Does protobuf-net support classes without a default constructor?"

Comment: @TheGeneral there are still nuances, though... answer incoming

Comment: Perhaps it would help (if that's possible) to add a parameterless constructor to the record definition. But have to admit, I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Funnily enough, my next statement was "insert Marc Gravell" :)

Comment: @PeterB that should also have fixed it, yes

Comment: Records are just normal classes in *most* of the sense and usage, however what you have defined is a *positional record* which does not have a parameterless constructor by default. You can, however, add one: `... ) { public GetServerProcessInfoResponse() : this(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.Zero, ...) { } }`

Comment: @TheGeneral The correct syntax would be `StackExchange.StackOverflow.ValuedAssociates.MarcGravell.Summon();`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Tweeting at Marc with an SO link also produces very good results :-)

Comment: Sif you need Twitter, the word allocations or a few key tags will awake the giant :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, in two different ways.

With your *existing* code, the simplest option is to tell protobuf-net to perform voodoo to get past the fact there is no available constructor; fortunately, this is simple:

```cs
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
public record GetServerProcessInfoResponse(
    [property: ProtoMember(1)] TimeSpan TotalProcessorTime,
    [property: ProtoMember(2)] TimeSpan UserProcessorTime,
    [property: ProtoMember(3)] TimeSpan PrivilegedProcessorTime,
    [property: ProtoMember(4)] string CurrentMemoryUsage,
    [property: ProtoMember(5)] string PeakMemoryUsage,
    [property: ProtoMember(6)] int ActiveThreads
);
```

However! With recent builds of the v3 code, it will also *infer* what you are trying to do *specifically in the case of purely positional records*, i.e. the following should work too, and mean *more or less* the same thing (as a minute detail: it will actually use the constructor in this case, instead of creating an instance via voodoo and then stomping the values):

```cs
public record GetServerProcessInfoResponse(
    TimeSpan TotalProcessorTime,
    TimeSpan UserProcessorTime,
    TimeSpan PrivilegedProcessorTime,
    string CurrentMemoryUsage,
    string PeakMemoryUsage,
    int ActiveThreads
);
```

Comment: Does it do this via reflection? Or is it cached?

Comment: Would you recommend one over the other? Is there a difference in performance? (Performance is important to me for this application). Thanks for replying so quickly!!

Comment: There is also the possibility of just adding the parameterless constructor to the record type.

Comment: @TheGeneral which "this"? all of the metadata discovery etc (looking at properties and attributes etc) is aggressively cached, if that is what you mean

Comment: @Moeri "if you want to know which horse is faster: race your horses" (personally I prefer the second version, on the basis that records are about brevity and removing ceremony)

Comment: If you can switch to a library, ProtoBuf, or otherwise, that can work with parameterized constructors, the plain positional record declaration would be my choice as well.

Comment: Yeah, I imagined it would have been :)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen (comment now deleted) - and that's why you're not allowed track-side any more

Comment: Yeah, benchmarkdotnet also had issues with my "solutions".

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks. One more question, if I may: does the attribute-less solution support inheritance then? (Can it also infer 'ProtoInclude'?)

Comment: @Moeri great question; I honestly haven't tried it; I probably should, but I *expect* the answer is "not today"

Comment: @MarcGravell FYI the attribute-less variant seems incompatible with protobuf-net.Grpc. When I drop the attributes, I immediately get "NotSupported" exceptions. Looks like the "SkipConstructor=true" route is the only option if you use Grpc.

Comment: @Moeri interesting; I'll have to look into that ASAP; it *should* be fine! Are you sure that you're referencing recent builds of protobuf-net v3 in that project?

Comment: @Moeri I've just checked the code, and the only place where it looks for `ProtoContractAttribute` is to check for the name, so it *should* work; I'll check. A full stack-trace and error message would help!

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm not sure if we should continue here in this little chat, but alright:
1. The full repository can be found here: https://github.com/amoerie/bidirectional. You should be able to simply run both server and client, they're simple .NET Core apps. In the client, press the "Get Server Info" button.
2. The stack trace, in my aptly named "GrpcService" is: 

System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at ProtoBuf.Grpc.Internal.Proxies.ClientBase.IGrpcService_Proxy_0.IGrpcService.GetAsync(GetServerProcessInfoRequest , CancellationToken )

Comment: I'll see if I can provide you with a simpler repro soon-ish.

Comment: @MarcGravell with some delay, here is my pull request that enables support for positional records with inheritance: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/pull/744

Comment: The second approach wont work if you class contains multiple constructors. Will throw exception if you have the ctor with all properties + empty ctor

Answer (score 3):

*Records* **will work**, and as comments and Marc's answer here shows, the issue is with the constructor, not that it is a record type.

Record types are just classes, with compiler-generated code and attributes.

To show a different way to get to where you want, you could just add the parameterless constructor. Yes, it's a little bit more work than just the naive record declaration, but if you're stuck with a version of ProtoBuf that doesn't support parameterized constructors, and you don't want to bypass the constructors like Marc showed, here's a different option:

```
[ProtoContract]
public record GetServerProcessInfoResponse(
    [property: ProtoMember(1)] TimeSpan TotalProcessorTime,
    [property: ProtoMember(2)] TimeSpan UserProcessorTime,
    [property: ProtoMember(3)] TimeSpan PrivilegedProcessorTime,
    [property: ProtoMember(4)] string CurrentMemoryUsage,
    [property: ProtoMember(5)] string PeakMemoryUsage,
    [property: ProtoMember(6)] int ActiveThreads
)
{
    public GetServerProcessInfoResponse() : this(default, default, default, default, default, default) { }
}
```

This lets you use the basic positional record declaration, but allows you to add the parameterless constructor that ProtoBuf <3 wants.

Comment: I need more coffee today, I don't know how many times I wrote `.Zeron` in this before I just went with `default`, and *positional* became *position* every time.

Comment: minor note: this *is* the "stomp the values" version - by which I meant, it creates the object with `new TheType()` if possible, falling back to a few other options (`Activator`, then voodoo) - and then calls `obj.Foo = x;`, `obj.Bar = y;` etc - as opposed to the fully parameterized constructor version, where it just does `new TheType(x, y, z)`

Comment: Ah, ok, so the "stomp the values" wasn't something related to the bypassing of the constructor bit, it was just the reflection bit. I'll update my answer then.

Comment: I do, however, like that records supports reflection like this, even with `init` properties, which still make deserialization libraries like Json.net and ProtoBuf work with these types without issues.