# Protobuf-Net Cannot Deserialize Record Without Parameterless Constructor

Tags: c#, deserialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Consider the following code example; I want to be able to serialize (which works fine) and deserialize (which doesn't work) the `Account` record using protobuf-net:

```cs
public abstract record State
{
    public abstract ISet<Identity> Identities { get; }

    public SerializedState Serialize()
    {
        using MemoryStream stream = new();
        Serializer.Serialize(stream, this);
        return new SerializedState(stream.ToArray(), GetType());
    }
}

public sealed record Account(Identity Owner, string Identifier, decimal Balance) : State
{
    public override ISet<Identity> Identities => new HashSet<Identity> {Owner};
}
```

The ProtoBuf contract configuration is effectively:

```cs
RuntimeTypeModel
    .Default
    .Add<Account>()
    .Add(nameof(Account.Owner))
    .Add(nameof(Account.Identifier))
    .Add(nameof(Account.Balance));
```

But I get the following exception:

> ProtoBuf.ProtoException: No parameterless constructor found for Example.Account

Is there a way to configure deserialisation (without using attributes) to allow records without parameterless constructors?

Comment: I think this previous answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65123415/214073

Comment: @KijanaWoodard I spoke to Marc Gravell about it ~in~directly. He said with inheritance as well, it's a little more complicated, but as yet, no official answer.

Comment: I don't suppose you could provide a [mcve] could you?  I suspect that the workaround from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65123415/214073 could be made to work, but your code doesn't compile so I can't say for sure.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/hSGMnE.

Comment: Seems like setting [`MetaType.UseConstructor = false`](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/protobuf-net/Meta/MetaType.cs#L1383) does work, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/N9siZk.  Does this answer your question?  If not, can you share a [mcve] showing what does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties of a record are, by default, [`init`-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record), and as such can actually be set by reflection by [protobuf-net](/questions/tagged/protobuf-net).  Thus your `Account` record can be deserialized by [protobuf-net](/questions/tagged/protobuf-net) by bypassing the constructor as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65123415/3744182) by [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) to *[Does protobuf-net support C# 9 positional record types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65123223/3744182)*.

Since you are initializing the contract for `Account` in runtime, modify your initialization code as to set [`MetaType.UseConstructor = false`](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/protobuf-net/Meta/MetaType.cs#L1383) as follows:

```
var accountMeta = RuntimeTypeModel
    .Default
    .Add<Account>()
    .Add(nameof(Account.Owner))
    .Add(nameof(Account.Identifier))
    .Add(nameof(Account.Balance));          
accountMeta.UseConstructor = false;
```

And now you can do:

```
var account = new Account(identity, "Foo", 1.1m);       
var state = account.Serialize();
var account2 = (Account)Serializer.NonGeneric.Deserialize(state.Type, new MemoryStream(state.Data));
```

Where I assume that `SerializedState` looks like:

```
public class SerializedState
{
    public SerializedState(byte [] data, Type type) => (Data, Type) = (data, type);
    
    public byte [] Data { get; set; }
    public System.Type Type { get; set; }
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N9siZk).

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, it really helped! I don't suppose you could look at my next question could you ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69383475/protobuf-net-surrogate-types-dont-deserialize-properly